# How to parse JSON using jQuery AJAX and display random articles

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to parse a JSON feed using the jQuery `ajax` method.

I am able to see the output if there is no pointer, so how to get the data with that?

And also, I want to show first 4 news as one option (I think inside the each function, I can do a for each?) but as an other option, I want to show random 4 news from that feed. Each time it can show 4 random news.

If possible, I also want to hide a news if its already read in that session, but I think this is complicated with jQuery.

Code so far:

**feed.json**

```
{
  "News": [{
      "title": "Story 1",
      "date": "2018-02-02 9:00:00 -0600",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.story.com\/",
      "description": " Description 1",
      "author": "Author 1",
      "image": "image1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Story 2",
      "date": "2018-02-02 9:00:00 -0600",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.story.com\/",
      "description": " Description 2",
      "author": "Author 2",
      "image": "image2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Story 3",
      "date": "2018-02-02 9:00:00 -0600",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.story.com\/",
      "description": " Description 3",
      "author": "Author 3",
      "image": "image3.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Story 4",
      "date": "2018-02-02 9:00:00 -0600",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.story.com\/",
      "description": " Description 4",
      "author": "Author 4",
      "image": "image4.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Story 5",
      "date": "2018-02-02 9:00:00 -0600",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.story.com\/",
      "description": " Description 5",
      "author": "Author 5",
      "image": "image5.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Story 6",
      "date": "2018-02-02 9:00:00 -0600",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.story.com\/",
      "description": " Description 6",
      "author": "Author 6",
      "image": "image6.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var displayResources = $('#newsContent');
  displayResources.text('Loading...');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "feed.json",
    success: function(result) {
      var output = '';
      $.each(result, function(i, item) {
        alert(result[i].title);
        output += "<li class='item total-4'>";
        output += "<a href=" + encodeURIComponent(result[i].title) + "><img  src=" + result[i].image + " /></a>";

        output += "<h4> <a href=" + result[i].url + " >" + encodeURIComponent(result[i].title) + "</a> </h4>";
        output += "</li>";
        displayResources.html(output);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>
      <span>News</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <ul id="newsContent"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Question: do you fetch the data feed only once per session, or multiple times?

Comment: Hi, it will be on a site so each time it will call the json feed and show the news. I haven't thought about caching. Is there any easy way? Or I can skip that for now. I think for your question once per session/many times  , it is many times as it will access the feed to get content.

Comment: What will trigger the access to the feed? (Yes, you can skip caching for now.)

Comment: just loading the page will make the call to the feed. show 4 news.

Comment: any help please?

Comment: `html` replaces any existing HTML with what is passed in. So in every iteration, you're replacing it. Set `html` outside the loop.